# Trying to use EventListener to change navbar on scroll, not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently trying to change the navbar on scroll to reduce its size and change the colors in it (specifically, change from transparent background to white, and change font colors). This is the HTML code:

```css
    /* Setting the overall html file font */
    html{
        font-family: "nunito", sans-serif;
        font-size: 10px;
    }
    
    /* Ensure no link coloring for any anchors */
     a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
          text-decoration: none;
          color: inherit;
     }
    
    /* Setting some desc for the container of the navbar */
    .wrapper{
        position: fixed; /* Keep it fixed */
        top: 0; /* 0 from the top */
        left: 0; /* 0 from the left */
        width: 100%; /* Make sure it fits the whole page */
        padding: 0 1.5rem; /* Since they're only two values, top and bottom are 0, left and right at 1.5rem */
        margin: 0 auto; /* Setting the margins */
        /* transition allows us to add transitions to elements in our html file */
        /* It takes first the argument of what to transition, then how fast, then the transition type */
        /* In our case, we change the background color, and would like to with ease */
        transition: background-color .5s ease; 
        /* We set the z-index, which defines the stack, to ensure it's always above anything */
        z-index: 9999;
    }
    
    /* Setting desc for the nav bar */
    .wrapper .navbar{
        width: 100%; /* Again ensure that the width is 100% */
        height: 10rem; /* Set height of the navbar to be 10rem */
        display: flex; /* flex */
        align-items: center; /* This defines alignment across cross axis, align all center (FLEX PROPERTY) */
        justify-content: space-between; /* This defines alignment across main axis, space between means fill out (FLEX PROPERTY) */
        border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.05); /* Setting the border at the bottom */
        padding: 0 30px;
    }
    
    /* Setting desc for the navbar logo */
    .wrapper .navbar-brand{
        color:black; /* For now, setting color to be black of the logo */
        font-size: 3.5rem; /* Setting the font size for the logo */
        font-weight:bold; /* Bold */
        float: left;
    }
    
    /* Setting desc for the header list */
    .wrapper .navbar .menu ul li{
        display: inline-block; /* Making it inline-block, so that the list is just horizontal */
        margin-top: 15px; /* Addting margin around, to make prettier */
        text-transform: uppercase; /* Make all text uppercase */
        letter-spacing: 3px;
    }
    
    
    .header-list{
      display: inline-block;
      float: none;
      vertical-align: top;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .navbar-collapse{
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    /* Setting desc for the header links of the navbar */
    .header-link{
        text-decoration: none;
        color:black;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 2rem;
    }
    
    /****************** Navbar Effects ******************/
    /* ::after is used meaning after each of the objects header-link, do the following */
    /* Here, we want to set it so that we add a line when we hover, right now we set what the actual */
    /* after should be */
    .header-link::after{
        content: ''; /* Used with ::after, shows what content would be shown after. Here, line */
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        background-color:black;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: -3px;
        /* ACTUAL TRANSFORMATION HERE, DIRECTION AND WHERE AND TYPE */
        /* We first define what the transformation would be, then the origin, then we define it in a */
        /* transition so that we could edit various thing */
        transform: scaleX(0);
        transform-origin: left;
        transition: transform .5s ease;
    }
    
    /* Effects for hovering on a link */
    .header-link:hover::after{
        transform: scaleX(1); /* Actually show the line under, scaleX(1) rather than 0 */
    }
    
    /* Some searchbar desc and effects (GENERAL) */
    .searchbar{
        position: relative;
    }
    
    /* Styling the text inside the search bar */
    .searchbar input[type="text"]{
      border: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 0px;
      height: 35px;
      border-radius: 3px;
    }
    
    /* Styling the icon for the search bar */
    .searchbar .icon{
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 35px; /* Setting the width */
      height: 100%; /* 100% height */
      background: none;
      border-radius: 3px;
      color:black;
      transition: all 0.5s 0.3s ease;
    }
    
    /* Span, or the actual glyphicon */
    .searchbar .icon span{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* Making sure the icon is in the box */
      cursor: pointer; /* Sets what the cursor would look like aka pointing to click */
    }
    
    /* Effects for when clicking on the icon */
    .searchbar .icon.active{
      background:beige;
      transition: all 0.3s ease; /* All means all properties of icon will have this effect */
    }
    
    /* Effects for when searching */
    .searchbar input[type="text"].active{
      width: 250px;
      padding: 0 10px;
      transition: all 0.5s 0.2s ease; /* Again, all properties. All setting effect duration to complete and so */
    }
    
    /* CENTERING AND MAKING SURE SAME LINE, FIXING NAVBAR */
    @media (min-width: 768px){
    #navbarNav.navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: flex!important;
        align-items: center;
        margin-top: 15px;
        flex-basis: auto !important;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    .navbar-toggler {display: none;}
    .navbar-brand {padding: 0 !important;}
    }
    
    ul li {margin-top: 0;}
    
    /* Fixing the navbar when we resize, collapsing */
    /* FROM https://codepen.io/RajRajeshDn/pen/dLgQbg */
    @media screen and (max-width: 1318px){
      .wrapper .navbar{
        padding: 0px;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 120px;
        justify-content: center;
      }
    
      .wrapper .navbar .menu{
        display: none;
      }
      .wrapper .navbar .menu ul li{
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 10px 0;
      }
      .searchbar .icon{
        margin-right: -20px;
      }
    }
    
    /****************** Scrolling Effects ******************/
    /* Effects for when scrolling is active */
    .scrolling-active{
      background-color: #fff; /* Change background color */
      box-shadow: 0 3px 1rem rgba(0,0,0,.1); /* Add box shadow */
    }
    
    /* Specifically changing the height of the navbar */
    .scrolling-active .nav{
      height: 6.6rem;
    }
    
    /* Changing height of the logo when scrolling */
    .scrolling-active .nav .navbar-brand img{
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
    }
    
    /* Changing the color of the line under the header links when scrolling */
    .scrolling-active .header-link::after{
      background-color: black;
    }
    
    ul li {margin-top: 0;}
    
    /* Hero Demo Content*/
    .hero{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: url("mountain-large.jpg") center no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .hero::after{
        content: '';
        width: inherit;
        height: inherit;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    }
    
    .demo-content{
        width: 100%;
        height: 200vh;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    
    <html>
        <!------------------------------ HEADER CODE ------------------------------>
        <head>
            <!-- Title for the project -->
            <title>Final Project</title>
            <!-- BOOTSTRAP LINK: CSS only -->
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
                integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <!-- BOOTSTRAP GLYPHICONS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <!-- PERSONAL CSS LINK -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        </head>
    
        <!------------------------------ BODY CODE ------------------------------>
    
        <body>
            <!------------------------------------------ NAVBAR ------------------------------------------>
            <header>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <nav class="navbar">
                        <!-- Logo segment -->
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><span><img src="./bunny.png" width="50" height="50"></span>US.</a>
                        <!-- Creating list for the other parts, so that we can give them all a specific effect -->
                        <div class = "menu">
                            <ul>
                                <!-- First text/link/point -->
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="index.html" class="header-link">Home Page</a>
                                </li>
                                <!-- Second text/link/point -->
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="header-link">Illustrator Gallery</a>
                                </li>
                                <!-- Third text/link/point -->
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="header-link">Art Gallery</a>
                                </li>
                                <!-- Fourth text/link/point -->
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="header-link">Challenges</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Creating a segment for the searchbar -->
                        <div class="searchbar">
                            <!-- Creating it as an input | placeholder is what text will show -->
                            <input type="text" placeholder="What speaks to you?">
                            <!-- The actual bootcamp glyphicon -->
                            <div class="icon">
                                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </header>
    
            <!-- Hero section -->
            <section class = "hero"></section>
            <section class = "demo-content"></section>
        </body>
    
        <!-- Script for changing the glyphicon search icon to a bar-->
        <!-- SNIPPER FROM https://codepen.io/RajRajeshDn/pen/dLgQbg -->
        <script>
            $(".glyphicon-search").click(function () {
                $(".icon").toggleClass("active");
                $("input[type='text']").toggleClass("active");
            });
        </script>
    
        <!-- Script for changing the effects when scrolling -->
        <script>
            // The event listener will essentially first be given the event, then the function on the event
            // The event is scrolling. For the function, we first define header as a selection of the header from the document
            // and define the windowPosition where the effect will take place as any Y scroll > 0
            // We then call classList.toggle(), meaning we'll toggle between classes to the active scrolling one
            window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
                let navHeader = document.querySelect('header');
                let windowPosition = window.scrollY > 0;
                navHeader.classList.toggle('scrolling-active', windowPosition)
            })
        </script>
    
    </html>
```

I'm not actually sure if the eventListener is working or not, or if there's something wrong with the code specifically. I'm aware that the code for the scrolling is entirely different from the searchbar script, mainly because for JS I'm taking snippets from different areas and trying to make sense of everything. I'm very new to this, so I'm not sure where the error is.

JSFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/3gjb0t2q/
(Note that the navbar gets condensed when the window size is small. I'm not sure if this adds to the problem as well)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It should be `let navHeader = document.querySelector('.wrapper');` at line 83 in HTML in fiddle

Answer (score 1):

There was a typo error in the fiddle. You typed `querySelect` which should be `querySelector`. Also you were accessing the wrong element. You need to access `.wrapper` not `header`.

```css
/* Setting the overall html file font */
html{
    font-family: "nunito", sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
}

/* Ensure no link coloring for any anchors */
 a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: inherit;
 }

/* Setting some desc for the container of the navbar */
.wrapper{
    position: fixed; /* Keep it fixed */
    top: 0; /* 0 from the top */
    left: 0; /* 0 from the left */
    width: 100%; /* Make sure it fits the whole page */
    padding: 0 1.5rem; /* Since they're only two values, top and bottom are 0, left and right at 1.5rem */
    margin: 0 auto; /* Setting the margins */
    /* transition allows us to add transitions to elements in our html file */
    /* It takes first the argument of what to transition, then how fast, then the transition type */
    /* In our case, we change the background color, and would like to with ease */
    transition: background-color .5s ease; 
    /* We set the z-index, which defines the stack, to ensure it's always above anything */
    z-index: 9999;
}

/* Setting desc for the nav bar */
.wrapper .navbar{
    width: 100%; /* Again ensure that the width is 100% */
    height: 10rem; /* Set height of the navbar to be 10rem */
    display: flex; /* flex */
    align-items: center; /* This defines alignment across cross axis, align all center (FLEX PROPERTY) */
    justify-content: space-between; /* This defines alignment across main axis, space between means fill out (FLEX PROPERTY) */
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.05); /* Setting the border at the bottom */
    padding: 0 30px;
}

/* Setting desc for the navbar logo */
.wrapper .navbar-brand{
    color:black; /* For now, setting color to be black of the logo */
    font-size: 3.5rem; /* Setting the font size for the logo */
    font-weight:bold; /* Bold */
    float: left;
}

/* Setting desc for the header list */
.wrapper .navbar .menu ul li{
    display: inline-block; /* Making it inline-block, so that the list is just horizontal */
    margin-top: 15px; /* Addting margin around, to make prettier */
    text-transform: uppercase; /* Make all text uppercase */
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}


.header-list{
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar-collapse{
  text-align: center;
}

/* Setting desc for the header links of the navbar */
.header-link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 2rem;
}

/****************** Navbar Effects ******************/
/* ::after is used meaning after each of the objects header-link, do the following */
/* Here, we want to set it so that we add a line when we hover, right now we set what the actual */
/* after should be */
.header-link::after{
    content: ''; /* Used with ::after, shows what content would be shown after. Here, line */
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color:black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -3px;
    /* ACTUAL TRANSFORMATION HERE, DIRECTION AND WHERE AND TYPE */
    /* We first define what the transformation would be, then the origin, then we define it in a */
    /* transition so that we could edit various thing */
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: left;
    transition: transform .5s ease;
}

/* Effects for hovering on a link */
.header-link:hover::after{
    transform: scaleX(1); /* Actually show the line under, scaleX(1) rather than 0 */
}

/* Some searchbar desc and effects (GENERAL) */
.searchbar{
    position: relative;
}

/* Styling the text inside the search bar */
.searchbar input[type="text"]{
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 0px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

/* Styling the icon for the search bar */
.searchbar .icon{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 35px; /* Setting the width */
  height: 100%; /* 100% height */
  background: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color:black;
  transition: all 0.5s 0.3s ease;
}

/* Span, or the actual glyphicon */
.searchbar .icon span{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* Making sure the icon is in the box */
  cursor: pointer; /* Sets what the cursor would look like aka pointing to click */
}

/* Effects for when clicking on the icon */
.searchbar .icon.active{
  background:beige;
  transition: all 0.3s ease; /* All means all properties of icon will have this effect */
}

/* Effects for when searching */
.searchbar input[type="text"].active{
  width: 250px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s 0.2s ease; /* Again, all properties. All setting effect duration to complete and so */
}

/* CENTERING AND MAKING SURE SAME LINE, FIXING NAVBAR */
@media (min-width: 768px){
#navbarNav.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: flex!important;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 15px;
    flex-basis: auto !important;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.navbar-toggler {display: none;}
.navbar-brand {padding: 0 !important;}
}

ul li {margin-top: 0;}

/* Fixing the navbar when we resize, collapsing */
/* FROM https://codepen.io/RajRajeshDn/pen/dLgQbg */
@media screen and (max-width: 1318px){
  .wrapper .navbar{
    padding: 0px;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 120px;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .wrapper .navbar .menu{
    display: none;
  }
  .wrapper .navbar .menu ul li{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .searchbar .icon{
    margin-right: -20px;
  }
}

/****************** Scrolling Effects ******************/
/* Effects for when scrolling is active */
.scrolling-active{
  background-color: #fff; /* Change background color */
  box-shadow: 0 3px 1rem rgba(0,0,0,.1); /* Add box shadow */
}

/* Specifically changing the height of the navbar */
.scrolling-active .nav{
  height: 6.6rem;
}

/* Changing height of the logo when scrolling */
.scrolling-active .nav .navbar-brand img{
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

/* Changing the color of the line under the header links when scrolling */
.scrolling-active .header-link::after{
  background-color: black;
}

ul li {margin-top: 0;}

/* Hero Demo Content*/
.hero{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url("mountain-large.jpg") center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.hero::after{
    content: '';
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.demo-content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200vh;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <!------------------------------ HEADER CODE ------------------------------>
    <head>
        <!-- Title for the project -->
        <title>Final Project</title>
        <!-- BOOTSTRAP LINK: CSS only -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- BOOTSTRAP GLYPHICONS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- PERSONAL CSS LINK -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>

    <!------------------------------ BODY CODE ------------------------------>

    <body>
        <!------------------------------------------ NAVBAR ------------------------------------------>
        <header>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <nav class="navbar">
                    <!-- Logo segment -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><span><img src="./bunny.png" width="50" height="50"></span>US.</a>
                    <!-- Creating list for the other parts, so that we can give them all a specific effect -->
                    <div class = "menu">
                        <ul>
                            <!-- First text/link/point -->
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="index.html" class="header-link">Home Page</a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Second text/link/point -->
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="#" class="header-link">Illustrator Gallery</a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Third text/link/point -->
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="#" class="header-link">Art Gallery</a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- Fourth text/link/point -->
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="#" class="header-link">Challenges</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Creating a segment for the searchbar -->
                    <div class="searchbar">
                        <!-- Creating it as an input | placeholder is what text will show -->
                        <input type="text" placeholder="What speaks to you?">
                        <!-- The actual bootcamp glyphicon -->
                        <div class="icon">
                            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>

        <!-- Hero section -->
        <section class = "hero"></section>
        <section class = "demo-content"></section>
    </body>

    <!-- Script for changing the glyphicon search icon to a bar-->
    <!-- SNIPPER FROM https://codepen.io/RajRajeshDn/pen/dLgQbg -->
    <script>
        $(".glyphicon-search").click(function () {
            $(".icon").toggleClass("active");
            $("input[type='text']").toggleClass("active");
        });
    </script>

    <!-- Script for changing the effects when scrolling -->
    <script>
        // The event listener will essentially first be given the event, then the function on the event
        // The event is scrolling. For the function, we first define header as a selection of the header from the document
        // and define the windowPosition where the effect will take place as any Y scroll > 0
        // We then call classList.toggle(), meaning we'll toggle between classes to the active scrolling one
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
            let navHeader = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
            let windowPosition = window.scrollY > 0;
            navHeader.classList.toggle('scrolling-active', windowPosition)
        })
    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I cannot express my pain at the number of hours I've spent on this but at least now it works haha

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it and the debugger says querySelect is not a function. You may be trying to use querySelector() instead. This might work for you.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
        let navHeader = document.querySelector('header');
        let windowPosition = window.scrollY > 0;
        navHeader.classList.toggle('scrolling-active', windowPosition)
    })
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! I am an absolute moron. Also, what debugger?